# Как сделать окна в стиле Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, style

Подскажите как сделать окна, в точности повторяющие стиль *Windows 7*?

Например, как эти

[image: прогресс-бар в стиле Windows 7]
[image: диалоговое окно в стиле Windows 7]

Comment: EnableVisualStyles?

Comment: а вы сами что-то пытались сделать?

Comment: В чем проблема, что конкретно не получается?

Comment: @SeeSharpь,  Igor Ilyichyov вы считаете, что все диалоги, включая диалоги стандартного вида, стоит писать с нуля, самому, не используя ничего готового?

Comment: Хотелось бы добиться таких окон через системный API. Это возможно?

Comment: @dmipin02, т.е. вы хотите чтобы эти окна выглядели как в Win7 при запуске на любой ОС?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Операционная система Windows поддерживает только один "хром" окон и не включает поддержку стилей хрома предыдущих версий Windows, поэтому **с помощью WinAPI вы не сможете добиться стиля Windows 7 на Windows 10**. (Условно поддерживается "классическая" тема, вроде, но это вас явно не интересует.)

Вы можете попытаться эмулировать стиль хрома предыдущей оси, но в случае эмуляции конкретно стиля Aero из Windows 7 это особенно трудно, потому что нужно воспроизвести не только все стили всех кнопок, но и прозрачность с замыливанием. Насколько мне известно, такой эффект может себе позволить ось, потому что она имеет эффективный доступ ко всем "слоям", а вот на уровне приложения его эмуляция будет затратна.

Картинки кнопок можно вытянуть из ресурсов системных библиотек Windows 7, но лицензионно это, разумеется, запрещено.

В целом я бы советовал вам не слишком увлекаться стилями хрома без веской на то причины. Пользователь ожидает, что хоть хром-то будет единообразен, по нему можно будет угадать, какое окно активно, например.

В приложениях, которые активно используют хром, например, в современных браузерах, которые размещают в заголовке ушки вкладок, обычно наоборот стараются воспроизвести текущий стиль оси.